# What does Build / rebuild truly builds?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process

I saw the suggested link  : 
What is the difference between a "build" and a "rebuild" in Visual Studio?

in stackOverflow but theres something strange :

I have project with many library dlls. ( projects)

If i add even a space into one *.cs file  , and press build on th project  - it scans **all**
the files in the project ( i see some outbput message for the other files - meaning that it scans them)

but in the article it says  - ONLY THE **CHANGED FILE**

my inspection is : **ALL THE SPECIFC PROJECT FILES**  WHERE THE ALTERED CS FILE

p.s. : what about reference to other projects? Does they always rebuild ?

i.e. : Project DLL **A** has reference to Project Dll **B**

when i Build **A**  - does **B** also REbuilds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Rebuild is a COMPLETE "Clean" (remove previous binaries) and Build each project, as per the order of Dependency
- Build is based on changed files + Dependency
- The fact that it scans all projects in your solution when you put a space to a *.cs file implies that this particular file is in a Core project where other projects are dependent upon
- Project DLL A is built will trigger a build on Project B, since B is dependent

Comment: Let me see if im right. **1)** if in project A i add a space to one of the many files in it , only those file in A which affected by the file which had the space change - will be build ? or the whole A project ? **2)** If i changed something in A and DIDNT changed in B ( which is a reference to A)  - does the B rebuild ?  (i didnt touched B...)

Comment: As far as MSBuild is concerned it can do a BUILD (involves Compiling, Linking (if needed) to create a Binary) on a Project - that is the objective of BUILD. **1)** So, if you change just a file in a project, it WILL go through the "Build Action" listed in the properties of all the files involved in the project. **2)** If you meant B "references" A - that implies B is dependent on A. So, Yes, it will rebuild B when A is rebuilt. If you meant B "is referenced in" A - that implies A is dependent on B. So, No, it will not rebuild B when A is rebuilt.

Comment: mmm for 2) - that wasnt the question.... the question was : If i change something in **A**, and **B** is depended on **A** (and i didn't change nothing on **B**) - and then i **BUILD A**, will B will be **BUILD** also...?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. My comment on 2) is wrong. If you just do a build of **project** A, it wont build B. But if you do a build on **Solution**, the dependencies will kick in thereby triggering a rebuild of B even though there is no change in B. And of course, Rebuild on a **Solution** rebuilds all, which you already know.